# How to convert 8 byte HEX to BIN

Tags: c++, binary-data

A small part of my thesis is to write code that converts a 8 byte HEX (like 12345678) input
to a bin (10010001101000101011001111000) output.

I have no idea how to start on this. I haven't taken any C++ lessons; I just saw a few tutorials. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I'll help you by saying [read a book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). You can't learn to write C++ by asking questions on Stack Overflow, and I'd rather you didn't try.

Comment: Check this link.. It might help u understand hex to bin http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php

Comment: I notice that your binary output starts with `1` rather than `0001`. Are you sure that's what you want? Usually binary representations are padded to some meaningful size (such as eight bits or thirty-two bits).

Comment: @ruakh: Maybe his value goes to the end of the padding.

Comment: Hope I never have to work with you.. especially since your question shows a total lack of research on behalf of a Masters student.

Comment: Agreed. That you haven't bothered to get any tuition or read any material besides "saw a few tutorials" before asking for free help on your _thesis_ is... mind-boggling. If you don't know C++ and aren't interested in learning it, then why are you incorporating it into a crucial project?

Comment: i am not a masters student, im 17 and i have to program things that i never have seen before. i have learned some of the basics but not all.

Comment: A thesis?  Really?   For what degree?

Comment: I hope your not working on a software related thesis.

Comment: i have to write a program that calculates the deviation of a new GPS module

detecting the right code >> splitting into longitude ant alititude >> convert to bin >> convert from IEEE754 to dec >> calculate deviation

Answer (score 2):

Think easy, think bits.

First you must decide whether the most significant bit (MSB) is output first, or the least significant bit (MSB).  For this example, I will show how to output least significant bit first.

### Binary Logic

The first concept to understand is the binary AND operator.  A 1 AND 0 is zero, a 1 AND 1 is 1, and 0 AND 0 is zero.  By using this operator, any bit can be isolated.

### Bit Shifting

Another concept is bit shifting. Shifting means moving each bit one position either right (dividing by 2) or left (multiplying by 2).  This concept will be used to determine which bit to isolate.

### Isolating zeros and ones

This algorithm will test a bit and and output a zero or a 1 for the bit's value:

```
if ((value & 1) == 0) cout << "0"
else cout << "1";
```

### Binary Output for an 8 bit unsigned integer:

Each bit will be tested by shifting a "mask" bit by 1 in a loop:

```
uint8_t mask = 1;    // Modify this line for outputting MSB.
uint8_t value = 0x5a; // 0101 1010
for (unsigned int count = 0; count < CHAR_BIT; ++count)
{
    if ((value & mask) == 0)
    {
        cout << "0";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "1";
    }
    mask = mask << 1;  // Modify this line to output MSB format
}
```

Applying this algorithm to multiple bytes is left to the reader. :-)

Comment: I know OPs question will be downvoted to oblivion, but thanks for giving them a solid and coherent answer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `std::bitset<>::to_string` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main () {
  unsigned long long x;
  std::cin >> std::hex;
  while(std::cin >> x) {
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(x).to_string() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all 8 byte HEX doesn't look like (12345678).
It is composed of two charachter (0-F) which both represents 4-bits 
like **0x41(HEX)  == 65(DECIMAL) == 01000001(BIN) == 'a'(CHAR) is equal to 1 BYTE**

and You have very good answer for your question if that was Your question really.

ps. uint8_t is "stdint.h" member and You wont find that everywhere(for example in VS)

Use unsigned char instead

```
unsigned char *r;
if(!(r=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*8)))
    return 0;
int arg = 65;
int i=0;
int p=0;
do{
p=(int)(pow(2,i));
    if (arg&p)
       r[7-i]=1;
    else
       r[7-i]=0;
    i++;                   
}while (i<8);
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
  printf("%d",r[i]);
getc(stdin);
```

**arg = 65**

**r = 01000001**

to print HEX from arg
   printf("%X",arg); or "%p" or "%x"

Here You have every bit of charachter stored in int array which means 4bytes for 1bit.

Of course c++ allows You to declare variable by HEX

```
**int arg = 0x41;**
```

Comment: In your first sentence, you confused "bits" with "bytes". The OP had it right.